# UPI deep link issue - iOS

Tags: ios, upi

This link is not working:

```
urlString = "upi://pay?pa=samplevpa@ybl&pn=Sample 
Name&am=1&cu=INR".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: 
.urlQueryAllowed)
```

It always opens the WhatsApp application.

How to use UPI deep link in iOS?

Comment: Because WhatsApp locked your UPI linking....try uninstall WhatsApp or install BHIM solved the problem for me.

Comment: How can they do it? Isn't it an OS dependent feature?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207671/upi-integration-using-deeplinking-in-ios

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273125/invoking-upi-apps-from-my-react-native-app-works-in-ios-but-not-in-android/67168090#67168090

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your mobile there are multiple UPI supported app installed. If not already installed then install and try.

> always opens the WhatsApp application

Because WhatsApp application introduces UPI-based payment feature and support to UPI deep linking.

Comment: it is not working even installed Phonepe, Gpay on my mobile.