# UPI integration using deeplinking in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-pay, upi

I am working on opening GooglePay, PhonePe or PayTM app when the user taps on Pay via UPI.

According to NPCI  docs https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf, when I try to open **upi://pay?parm-name=param-value&param-name=pram-value&...** or essentially **upi://** from mobile browser, it randomly opens any UPI installed application (whatsApp in my case) and if whatsApp isn't installed, it opened PayTM.

I want a behaviour in my app where if a user taps on Pay via GooglePay, GooglePay app should open with prefilled amount and merchant linked to it just like how CRED app does it.

How can I achieve a similar functionality?

PS I tried **tez://**, it opens GooglePay app but it isn't documented anywhere so I don't know if I can rely on it.

Edit: Can I achieve it without using SDK? I want to use only URL scheme to achieve it.

Comment: People who are downvoting it, can you please comment here why is it being downvoted?

Comment: Can you please share the code for the same you did using tez:// ?

Comment: Did you end up getting it working? If so, do you want to help out with the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529370/how-to-integrate-google-pay-in-ios-swift)? StackOverflow seems to be short of some working code samples for UPI integration on iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't documented either but the two schemes that you might want to try are:

- `tez://upi/*`
- `gpay://upi/*`

If I had to take a guess about which one will be better supported it would be the `gpay` option.

#### Update

I've tried and it doesn't look like the URI's I provided above work. See https://internal-absorbed-celsius.glitch.me/

Comment: It works fine in iOS 15. Just checked it, but is there any way to do PhonePe & other apps?

Comment: Already there is an solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67168090/2751119