# Google pay UPI integration in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, integration, google-pay, upi

I am working on an asp.net application where we want to implement the Google pay UPI payment method. It should work in the following way when the user clicks on the payment button the control redirects to the users' mobile app and shows the payment request from the Google pay mobile application.
Can anyone find me the related docs or links to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [UPI linking specification (page 5)](https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf).

In your case, you would generate a `upi://` link with the required parameters. Note that this will launch any UPI mobile app on the user's device. <del>If you want to target the Google Pay app (for India), you should use `gpay://upi/` as a prefix instead.</del>

<del>See also my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207671/upi-integration-using-deeplinking-in-ios).</del>