# Invoking UPI apps from my react-native App works in iOS but not in Android

Tags: android, react-native, google-pay, paytm, upi

I am trying to invoke few common UPI Apps (`Google Pay`, `Phone Pay`, `PayTM`) using `deep links`.

```js
openPaymentApp = async (payApp) => {
    let url = '';
    switch(payApp) {
        case 'PAYTM'   : url = 'paytmmp'; break;
        case 'GPAY'    : url = 'gpay'; break;
        case 'PHONEPE' : url = 'phonepe'; break;
    }
    url = url + '://upi/pay?pa=7024293076@upi&pn=DK Bose&mc=0000&tr=123456789ABCDEFG&tn=HelloWorld&am=11&cu=INR'
    console.log('URL : ',url);
    try {
        await Linking.openURL(url);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error('ERROR : ',err);
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <View style={{alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center",flex:1}}>
            <Button title='PAYTM'    onPress={() => this.openPaymentApp('PAYTM')}/>
            <Button title='GPAY'     onPress={() => this.openPaymentApp('GPAY')}/>
            <Button title='PHONE PE' onPress={() => this.openPaymentApp('PHONEPE')}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

It works fine in iOS, i.e on opening the Deep Links the respective apps open up and the app automatically jumps to the UPI payments page with pre filled fields of VPA, Name, Amount, Note etc.

But on Android i have following problems :

- `GPay` : App does not open.
- `Paytm` : App opens but does not go to UPI payments page
- `PhonePe` : App opens but does not go to UPI payments page

When I tried using default upi deeplink, on android it gives a popup to select a UPI app. But only Google Pay and iMobile (from ICICI) are listed there, Paytm and Phonepe are not listed in that popup.

```
upi://pay?pa=7024293076@upi&pn=DK...
```

**Are `Deeplinks` for UPI payment Apps different for iOS and Android ?**

What else needs to be done to open the App and move to UPI payment page with pre filled fields ?

Comment: in my case gpay app opend couldn't make payment facing issue "your money has not been debited"

Answer (score 4):

Working deep links for these android apps are:

Paytm:

```
paytmmp://pay?pa=your@vpa&pn=YourName&tn=Note&am=1&cu=INR
```

Phonepe:

```
phonepe://pay?pa=your@vpa&pn=YourName&tn=Note&am=1&cu=INR
```

GPay

```
tez://upi/pay?pa=your@vpa&pn=YourName&tn=Note&am=1&cu=INR
```

Comment: in my case facing "Your money has not been debited"

Comment: I guess (don't know, only guessing) UPI somehow blocks these links if they are not generated by some authorised merchant app (I guess they think these can be misused by scammers).

Comment: did you find solution @Ajith?

Answer (score 0):

I am solving in one way but it's not the best solution I know.  So far i am solving the issue by redirecting it to a browser in params and from browser i am opening intent link.

Example-

> [www.website.com?paymentinfo=intent://pay?pa=payu@axisbank&pn=company](http://www.website.com?paymentinfo=intent://pay?pa=payu@axisbank&pn=company)
> LIMITED&tr=12703860471&tid=COBya9xXv2VWZ7Zc&am=4.00&cu=INR&tn=OrderId-COBya9xXv2VWZ7Zc#Intent;scheme=upi;package=com.phonepe.app;S.browser_fallback_url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonepe.app&hl=en_IN;end

after receiving payment info i am opening in browser using **window.open(paymentinfo)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you are looking for.
The code should look something like this:

```
 openPaymentApp = async (payApp) => {

    let url = '';
    switch(payApp) {
        case 'PAYTM'   : url = 'paytmmp://'; break;
        case 'GPAY'    : url = 'tez://upi/'; break;
        case 'PHONEPE' : url = 'phonepe://'; break;
    }
    url = url + 'pay?pa=7024293076@upi&pn=DK Bose&mc=0000&tr=123456789ABCDEFG&tn=HelloWorld&am=11&cu=INR'
    console.log('URL : ',url);
    try {
        await Linking.openURL(url);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error('ERROR : ',err);
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <View style={{alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center",flex:1}}>
            <Button title='PAYTM'    onPress={() => this.openPaymentApp('PAYTM')}/>
            <Button title='GPAY'     onPress={() => this.openPaymentApp('GPAY')}/>
            <Button title='PHONE PE' onPress={() => this.openPaymentApp('PHONEPE')}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: What is the url for other upi apps like amazon pay, iMobile pay etc.

Comment: You can just google for the respective link. @RohannnSingh

Comment: @GavinD'mello do you have the deeplinks for other upi apps? I'm unable to find them through google (yet).