# UPI apps not opening from Iphone browser but its working on Android

Tags: javascript, html, google-pay, upi

```
<a href="upi://pay?pa=UPIID@oksbi&amp;pn=FNAME SNAME K&amp;cu=INR" class="upi-pay1">Pay Now !</a>
```

When we use the above code the apps like GooglePay, PhonePe, Whatsapp, Paytm working in Android, but same url opens always whatsapp in Iphone

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61207671/upi-integration-using-deeplinking-in-ios and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273125/invoking-upi-apps-from-my-react-native-app-works-in-ios-but-not-in-android/67168090#67168090

Comment: Hi Mani, We have the exact issue. Were you able to fix this? Please let us know. It'll be very helpful.

Comment: @Mani Was this fixed?